# Optimization for a capacity problem

Tags: python, gurobi, packing

I have a csv file with a table with 5 columns: dueDateTime, cover, phone, simcard, tablet.

This file has the amount of items for cover, phone, simcard, tablet.

I have the size of the items:

we have cover :   20cm x 10cm x 3cm
we have phone  :  15cm x 9cm x 8cm
we have simcard :  9cm x 6cm x 1cm
we have tablet :  26cm x 20cm x 6cm

I have the capacity of each ship: 40cm x 40cm x 60cm

Now I want to minimize the amounts of ships I need to use. Each Item can go into any ship.

The problem is that we cannot cut the items in half. So its hard to use the volume in the calculation.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! I suggest you show your formulation and progress and where you got stuck to get better answers.

Comment: Question has also been asked in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325495 without further details...

Comment: What is the dueDateTime for? This looks like a classical 3D bin packing problem